# Creating a grid of plots in the shown arrangement

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

How can I use Grid to create the shown arrangement of plots:

[image]

Comment: See documentation for [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and [`SpanFromLeft`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpanFromLeft.html)

Answer (score 4):

As Bob Hanlon pointed out, the trick is to use SpanFromLeft. In the particular case here, the following will do the job:

```
Grid[{{TL, TR}, {ML, MR}, {B, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All]
```

You can replace the simple text (i.e, "TL", for example) with a plot you have named prior to creating the Grid.